# Dead Links, what to do with them?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

I was hopping around, tag-updating, and I came across [this situation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4159/which-episode-of-star-trek-tng-is-this-image-from) for the second time in two days:

[image]

I considered just removing the link and saying it was from the 'chat-room', but at the same time, I didn't want to retcon a lack of thoroughness in the original question.  So you see my edit.

What's the ideal way to handle this?

Comment: from the chat room ***not available*** page

Comment: A more correct way to phrase this would have been (feel free to update if you like): "This image is from Meta Stack Overflow's custom error page which shows when the chat room requested is not available".

Comment: Ooops, no, this wasn't about a local chat-room.  This is the first time _that's_ happened in my wanderings.  Just dead-links in general.

Answer (score 8):

The link from that question isn't to a specific chat room, and still goes exactly where it is supposed to go (for me, at least).

Read the description again.

The link points to the custom "chat room not found" page, because *that is the page that has the image the OP is asking about*.

In general, the best way to handle dead links is to find an appropriate replacement URL, and fix the link without changing content.

Failing that, removing the link and putting a notice that the link no longer works is appropriate.  However, in those cases, you should include a text version of the original link, as the context of the URL might potentially be helpful (either in providing information about what the citation was, or clues for those looking to fix it).

Just make sure the link really *is* broken, first.

Comment: Oy, okay- gotcha.